# How to rotate tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I signed up yet so sorry for such a simple question!
I want tabs that switch automatically every 5 seconds, for example, how to implement it?
my code:
html code:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">first</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">third</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">fourth</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">fifth</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <img src="first.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <img src="second.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <img src="third.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <img src="fourth.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="tab5" class="tab">
            <img src="fifth.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to demonstrate what you have tried and why it didn't work. **This is not a code writing service**.

Comment: i have no idea? my knowledge in js very poor

Comment: Then you are in the wrong place, unfortunately.

Comment: well understood sorry to trouble

Comment: Everyone here helps because they enjoy helping, not because it's their job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
var current_tab = 1;
var number_of_tabs = 5;
window.setInterval(function(){
    if(current_tab == number_of_tabs){
        current_tab = 1;   
    }else{
        current_tab++;
    }
    $('#tab'+current_tab).show().siblings().hide();    
    $('#tab'+current_tab).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}, 5000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ve4sg/1/